# Callback not executing asynchronously in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, nonblocking

A callBack function:

```
function queryDemo(param,callBack){
    function sleep(milliSeconds) {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
    } 
    sleep(10000);
    callBack(param);
}
```

Express code:

```
app.get('/demo', function(req, res){
    console.log(1);
    queryDemo(JSON.stringify(req.query),function(result){
        console.log(2);
    });
    console.log(3);
});
```

Then browse `http://127.0.0.1/demo`, the output in console is

```
1
//wait 10 seconds here
2
3
```

I think the right output should be:

```
1
3
// 10 seconds later
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback will execute synchronously unless you queue it to run on the next iteration of the event loop. This is what [`process.nextTick()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) is used for.

```
function queryDemo(param, callback) {
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliseconds);
  } 
  sleep(10000);
  process.nextTick(function() {
    callback(param);
  });
}
```

However, if you use this, you will still block the application and get this output:

```
1
// 10 second pause
3
2
```

To delay the execution of the function itself, then queue the calling of the function itself:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
  queryDemo(JSON.stringify(req.query), function(result) {
    console.log(2);
  });
});
```

Also do note that your `sleep()` function will still block the application, so you should be using `setTimeout()` instead.

Comment: Point to add: Even the OP is using callback, the calling is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are killing the thread with that tight loop.  Why are you trying to write you own sleep function instead of the [built in timers](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html) `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?